# How do I set the app proxy URL for a Shopify app?

Tags: proxy, fetch, shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

I understand that I need to set up an app proxy to make requests to my Postgres DB and for the app-extensions. However, I keep getting 404 errors for a bad URI - I'm not understanding how to do this properly.

All I want to do is post to Postgres (on Heroku) by making a frontend call to my API. The app-proxy config is attached below.

I'm trying to make an authenticaed call via **useFetch()** hook:
**merchant.tsx**

```js
const BASE_URL = "/apps/my-app-proxy";
const postBody = {
  id: 1,
  name: "Test",
  account: "0x.....",
  campaign_id: 1,
};

useFetch(`${BASE_URL}/api/merchant/`, {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application.json",
          "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(postBody),
        method: "POST",
      }).then((res) => {
        console.log("POST merchant: ", res);
      });
```

The response returns as: [404: JSON Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T55n5.png)
The App proxy config I am using: [App Proxy config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkNLN.png)

The endpoints in merchant.ts are NOT being hit. How do I actually call the proxy url to call my endpoints?

**index.ts:**

```js
    // add new routes with router in here
    app.use("/api/merchant", merchantRouter);
```

**merchant.ts:**

```js
import express from "express";
import { Merchant } from "../models/Models";
const router = express.Router();
// NOTE: These routes deal with all merchant requests

// TODO: connect database to shopify
// Authentication to prevent aanyone from calling
// or already done by shopify?
router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        // TODO: check if merchant already exsits (shopify acc/email?)
        console.log('MERCHANT ENDPOINT')
        const merchant = req.body;
        await Merchant.create(merchant);
        res.json(merchant);
    } catch (e) {
        console.error('ERROR: ', e);
    }
})

router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    console.log('GET MERCHANTS called ', req)
    const merchants = await Merchant.findAll();
    res.json(merchants);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error("ERROR: ", e);
  }
});

router.get("/:id", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const id = req.params.id;
    const merchant = await Merchant.findByPk(id);
    res.json(merchant);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error("Error: ", e);
  }
});

export default router;
```

Comment: You made an request on URL that contain /apps/ and into backend /app/ is added, did you check the same?

Comment: @Onkar Yeah, I just changed the app-proxy URL to the ngrok URL being hosted and whenever I try to navigate to any of the URL's I get the app-bridge error:  
"APP::ERROR::INVALID_CONFIG: host must be provided"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off. In Shopify, App setup, Proxy. You decide your internal App endpoint. That will be your ngrok address plus whatever accepts a GET or POST from Shopify. You also get to tell Shopify what URL you want the front-end store to use. That is your choice of /a/foo or /tools/hammer or /community/beers or whatever.

Note that with these things set in Shopify, the merchant can still tinker in their Admin, and change your nice /a/foo to /a/poo and you'd never know.

In your front-end code, in the store theme, you want to access your proxy, so you write some JS to do a GET or POST to match what your App expects, sending the request to /a/foo or whatever you set in your App.

It really is both that easy and that frustratingly hard. Why oh why! App Proxy, forever in my heart. Forever hard to deal with.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'm trying to cal this endpoint 'https://4ff4-82-34-171-158.ngrok.io/apps/my-app-proxy/api/merchant/' but I'm going a 404 error. I set up the /api/merchant route in the backend - is there something else I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You don't provide your front-end call code that is 404. Either you're not calling the URL you setup in App Proxy setup eg: /a/gooble or something else is up. Check your console network debug panel for where you're calling your proxy from and fix that. Shopify ensures that calls your App URL correctly.

Comment: The front-end call code is in the main post. I am using the /apps/my-app-proxy BASE URL and then /api/merchant for my endpoint. I also tried calling the storefront directly, thinking it would forward my request to the proxy URL, but just get a CORS error.

Comment: The point of a Proxy is to NOT call your App at all. Clear that that should generate a CORS error! So your goal in the front-end is to call the App Proxy url /a/gooble or whatever. If that is coming up 404, it means your App itself is not responding to Shopify, and you have to work on that aspect of your routing setup. GET or POST at thr right place.

Comment: Ok. I'm able to call my endpoint WITHOUT the app proxy url - by just calling 
 https://xxx.ngrok.io/api/merchant 
Does this mean I don't need the app proxy at all or just because i'm using ngrok and it's not a live app yet?

Comment: YOU DO NOT call the proxy. Shopify calls the Proxy. They use your secret key from the App install to make a header value you can use for security purposes!! 

Call the proxy using your JS. /tools/widget or whatever it is you set.

Comment: Late to the party, and this may well be a stupid question, and I get how this works in dev, but for a live app where the endpoint is within the app, what do we replace the ngrok address with? The full app URL seems like a fishy solution but maybe I'm overthinking it?

`https://admin.shopify.com/store/my-store/apps/my-app/app/my-remix-endpoint` ?

Comment: It is an endpoint in your App. So Shopify knows the address of your App and it is NOT ngrok for production. Whatever you set your Shopify App itself to is where Shopify sends the data.